# How to set a generic method which already exists in a used package?

Tags: r, oop, r-s4

I am modifying a S4-Class `s4c` and want to add a method `index`. Since the class is widely used in my custom package, renaming is no choice. Therefore I do

```
setGeneric(where = environment(), name="index", 
           def=function(x,include.from=T, include.to=T) standardGeneric("index")
           )
#' @export
setMethod(
  f = "index",
  signature = "s4c",
  definition = function (x, include.from, include.to) {
...
```

The method works. My problem is that I want to use the `zoo`-package also, where a generic function `index` already exists. If I load and attach the package I get the message

> The following objects are masked *by* ‘.GlobalEnv’:
>       index

and, suppose `z` to be a object of class `zoo` if I type `index(zoo)` I get the error

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :    unable to find an
>   inherited method for function ‘index’ for signature ‘"zoo"’

Previously I worked with a more S3-like approach like

```
index.s4c <- function (x, include.from, include.to) {
...
```

and it worked. But I want to avoid this to get a 'pure' S4-class. 
My attempt to work with a local environment via `where = environment()` does not work. How to deal with this?

Many thanks, Mika

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setGeneric` to create an S4 generic `index` which uses the S3 generic as default as shown in the line marked ### below.  Then test it out by creating a new class `"A"` with component `x` and an object of that class to test it out with:

```
library(zoo)

setGeneric("index") ###

# test it out

setClass("A", representation(x = "numeric"))
setMethod("index", "A", function(x) x@x)
a <- new("A", x = 99)
index(a)      # index works on an object of our new class A
## [1] 99


z <- zoo(100) # zoo object with value 100 and index 1
index(z)      # index still works on zoo objects
## [1] 1
```

Comment: It seems that I have to load `zoo` before I can do `setGeneric("index")`. Is it possible to define the `index`-method first (because I need `zoo` only for parts of my package)?

Comment: Try: `setGeneric("index", zoo::index)`